# CreateDeploymentBySlot phase of deployment takes a long time

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment

So, all of a sudden, my Azure cloud service (1 web role and 2 worker roles) deployments have gone from taking something like 13 minutes

```
6/22/2015 6:43:47 PM    CreateDeploymentBySlot  Succeeded   
6/22/2015 6:29:54 PM    CreateDeploymentBySlot  Started
```

to taking 40 minutes and over

```
7/2/2015 12:19:29 PM    CreateDeploymentBySlot  Succeeded
7/2/2015 11:39:30 AM    CreateDeploymentBySlot  Started
```

to perform the same operation (CreateDeploymentBySlot) when deploying to an empty staging slot.

This significantly increase the time it takes to deploy my cloud service.

There have only been minor, non-azure related code-changes in the service since it deployed at a speedier rate.

I'm using the "Publish Azure Application" feature to publish to Azure (Visual Studio 2012). It's available as option "Publish" when right-clicking an Azure Cloud Service project in the solution explorer.

After the package is uploaded, it seems that nothing happens for at least 25 minutes, both with the VS tools for monitoring Azure services, nor in either the old or the new management portal. At around the 30 minute mark, Azure finally decides to start creating the VMs, and from therein, everything happens as promptly as it used to.

How can I establish the cause of this unpleasant delay?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can try to deploy your cloud service on local Azure emulator and check